# Regarding Setting text of a WebElement without using SendKeys method

Tags: selenium, ios

I have the following code piece in java using selenium inorder to access UI element on iOS and populate a textfield.

```
WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//window[1]/textfield[1]"));
username.click();
username.clear();
username.sendKeys("User");
```

The `sendKeys()` method accesses the keyboard of the phone and i want to be able to do the same without accessing the keyboard of the phone.Is there some way to do this by kind of setting the value in code without using keyboard of the phone.

Answer (score 4):

One way I can think of a avoiding using `sendKeys()` is to execute a Javascript function that will set the value of the web element. The below example assumes JQuery is available on the page:

```
driver.executeScript("$('window>textfield').val('User');");
```

Comment: Using pure javascript is pretty simple too: driver.executeScript("arguments[0].value = 'User'", username);